# <div align="center"></div> is this bad?

Tags: html, alignment

Is it considered bad practice to use `align="center"` in `<div>` tags?

Comment: true, don't use align, http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_div_align.asp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could have a class of center in your CSS which works for most block elements.

For the CSS code:

```
.center {margin:0 auto;}
```

In your HTML:

```
<div class="center">Content Here</div>
```

If you wanted the text to be aligned center aswell as the div then you would just update the above CSS to be:

```
.center {margin:0 auto; text-align:center;}
```